# In Harry Potter can you have a do-over year?

Tags: harry-potter

In Belgium, you sit in a class have and X kind of courses. If you fail like 2-3 courses at the end of the year, you'll have to follow all those courses again in High School. Is this also possible in the Harry Potter movies? I could understand if you fail for 1 course, you'll have to redo that single course in Hogwarts.

I know they take exams and such, but is there anyone who wasn't allowed to go to the next stage / year? And had to redo his courses? I didn't really notice anyone in the movie franchise.

Comment: It certainly *used* to be done in UK schools but them I'm old.. *but it was very rare*.

Comment: https://educationendowmentfoundation.org.uk/evidence-summaries/teaching-learning-toolkit/repeating-a-year/

Comment: https://yougov.co.uk/news/2012/04/27/holding-pupils-back-year/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes.

**Marcus Flint**

[image]

> Marcus Flint (b. 1974/1975) was a wizard who attended Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry from 1986 to 1994 and was sorted into Slytherin house. He was a Chaser on the Slytherin Quidditch team, as well as its Captain from 1991 to 1994. **Flint had to repeat his final year of education, as he failed his exams the first time round.**
>
> <sup>[Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Marcus_Flint)</sup>

---

That said..

> Flint was stated to be a sixth year in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, yet he was still at the school in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (two years after his debut). **J. K. Rowling explained this by saying that he had to repeat his last year.** This explanation did not deter some fans from noticing other consistency errors with Flint's schooling years. **In later editions of Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, however, Flint is stated to be a fifth year, presumably to clear confusion.**